# How to checkout a subfolder from a local svn copy (and not the svn server)?

Tags: windows, svn

For some simple Windows batch script, I want to temporarily create a copy of a certain folder in an local working copy of an svn repository at a certain revision. I do not want to checkout directly from the svn server (because then my script needs to know what the server address is, and potentially I would need to authenticate etc.)
And I can not just copy the subfolder, as the hidden .svn folder is higher up.

I have been trying some variations on (with the `repo` folder containing the `.svn` hidden folder):

```
svn co file:///E:/repo/paper@48 E:/temprepo
```

But that doesn't work. My Windows 7 command prompt answers with

```
svn: E180001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///E:/repo/paper'
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///E:/repo/paper'
```

I am doing something wrong, or is what I am trying impossible?

Comment: The working copy is not a repository. You can only get the revisions currently checked out to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems bit ambiguous. I can think of two ways of looking at this.

1. Assuming you just want a copy of a sub-folder in a svn working copy WITHOUT the .svn folders.
   You can use `svn export` to copy a given sub-folder of a working copy like this - `svn export E:\repo\paper E:\temprepo`.
2. Quote:

   > And I can not just copy the subfolder, as the hidden .svn folder is
   >   higher up.

   *EDIT:* This file structure is only available in subversion v 1.7. In a subversion client with version 1.6.x sub-folders in a working copy should be self-contained. Meaning you may duplicate it to another place, and do subversion operations like `svn update` etc. in it.

Comment: The export will not be able to commit later. Also, the sub-folders aren't self-contained. I just tested it with svn 1.7 and I believe it's not self-container too with svn 1.6 despite the fact that with 1.6 each directory have a .svn.

Comment: This answer is based assuming subversion v 1.6, specifically 1.6.12. Yes, in subversion 1.7 sub-folders are NOT self contained. But in 1.6 IT IS. As I said you can do svn operations like `svn update` `svn commit` in an isolated sub-folder. I have updated my answer with this info. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You actually solved my 'real' problem! The command `svn export -r 48 E:\repo\paper e:\temprepo` is the one I was looking for! Thanks. (Seems you got a downvote for the .svn folder thing, so my upvote only gets you to zero :-()

Answer (score 1):

As you have rightly mentioned in your question, you have working copy of subversion repository and not the repository it self.

You can check out only for a repository that happens to be your subversion server.

When you check out your repository, a pristine version of the repository contents are located inside the ".svn" folders.

This is how svn shows you the diff when your working copy differs from the original contents without routing it's request to server.

It also keeps meta data of your server address and other information which you can see when you do `svn info`. This also contains your server address as svn url.

Your working copy and the ".svn" folders fully recognize the repository from which it was checked out.

I hope you have understood why you can not checkout from your own working copy.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. (KasunBG gave me the clue on how to solve it, though)